# LINQ Query - Display customers with their number of orders including the customer with no orders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, visual-studio-2015

In the following LINQ Query I need to display `All` the customers with total number of their orders placed including the customers that have not placed any orders:

**Models**:

```
Public class Customer
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
}

Public class Order
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ Query**: Question: How can I display `ALL` customers (including the one that have no order) and total number of orders per customer (zero for those whose customerID is not in Orders table)

```
var Query1 = from c in Customers
             join o in Orders into co
             from t in co.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {CustomerID = c.CustomerId, OrderID = (t == null ? 0 : t.OrderId)};
```

Comment: if there is a relationship between customers and orders you do not need to join, and just adapt your select statemebt by something like this.
select new {CustomerID = c.CustomerId, TotalOrders = (t == null ? 0 : c.Orders.Count())};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to do a LEFT JOIN between your Customer table and Customer Order table and then do a group by on that result to count the orders for each customer.

Assuming you have a class like this

```
public class CustomerOrder
{
  public int CustomerId { set; get; }
  public int? OrderId { set; get; }
}
```

*This class is to store each item for the left join result*

Now, you need to first do a LEFT JOIN and project the result of that to a list of `CustomerOrder` class objects, Then do a GroupBy on top of that

```
var usersWithCount = (from c in db.Customers
    join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId 
    into result
    from sub in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new CustomerOrder{  OrderId= sub!=null ? sub.OrderId :(int?) null,
                                    CustomerId = u.CustomerId }
) // Here we have the left join result.
.GroupBy(g => g.CustomerId , (k, orders) => new { 
                    CustomerId = k, 
                    OrderCount = orders.Count(t=>t.OrderId !=null)}).ToList();
```

The result stored in `usersWithCount` will be a collection of annonymous object with a `CustomerId` and `OrderCount` property.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very efficient since it iterates through `Orders` for every customer, but it'll get the job done:

```
var query = Customers
    .Select(c => new
        {
            Name = c.Name,
            NumOrders = Orders.Count(o => o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId)
        });

foreach (var result in query)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", result.Name, result.NumOrders);
```

Comment: This will generate a sub-query per customer, not efficient at all !

Comment: @SirajMansour That's exactly what I already said at the top of my answer. Thanks for confirming though...

Comment: Are you sure you get subqueries in that case? Usually, I would used LinqPad to verify if that would be the case. However, in that case, I would have written the query as written in Laurent comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Query1 = from c in Customers
     join o in Orders on c.CustomerId equals o.CustomerId into OrdersGroup
    from item in OrdersGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new Order { OrderId = 0, CustomerId = 0 })                      
    select new {CustomerID = c.CustomerId, OrderID = (item == null ? 0 : item.OrderId)};
```

this will return all customers (even if they have no orders ) and orders

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BoHx2d